# Facet/separate boxplots in R when formula is used and outliers are not drawn? (ggplot2 or r basics)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame like that called ***samples_type***:

```
Status   variable        value
PAT       SPP1        1,994629e+00
PAT       SPP1        1,179033e+00
PAT       SPP1        2,901539e+00
PAT       SPP1        1,140857e+00
PAT       SPP1        1,467056e+00
PAT       SPP1        2,579037e+00
```

The "Status" column can take two values: PAT or CON.
The "variable" column can take many values: *SPP1, CCL24, ENG56 ...*

I would like to make boxplots of values for each combination of Status:variable.

For the moment I have two codes:

```
boxplot(value ~ Status:variable, data=samples_type,
col=c("red", "limegreen"), las=2, outline=F)
```

and:

```
p0 <- ggplot(data = samples_J0_type, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Status)) +
facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free")
```

The first code give me all the boxplots in ONE GRAPH without outliers. I want to separate them as ***par(mfrow=c(...,...))*** will do it. **How can I do that?**

With the second code I used ggplot2. I managed to separate the boxplots **BUT** as you can see, I didn't manage to delete the outliers and my boxplots are to small because of the outliers. **How can I delete the outliers?** I checked on StackOverFlow how to delete outliers with ggplot2, I found an answer for ONLY ONE boxplot but not for multiple boxplots. And I have no idea on how to do that...

**EDIT: boxplots of each code**

[image: Boxplot with the first code]
[image: Boxplot with the second code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General**

A bit difficult to help as you are not providing a minimal data set, so I have to fall back to existing data.

```
mt <- mtcars %>% select(cyl, mpg, am)
## add some outliers
mt <- rbind(mt, data.frame(cyl = c(4, 6, 8), mpg = rep(100, 3), am = 0))
```

**Base R**

You can split your data according to one of your variables, set the `mfrow` accordingly and use an `apply` function to generate each plot separately:

```
## split your data according to one variable
dl <- split(mt, mt$am)

## set the mfrow
par(mfrow = 1:2)
## something more educated would be something like this
## needs to be adapted for border cases
## par(mfrow = c(ceiling(sqrt(length(dl))), ceiling(sqrt(length(dl)))))

## loop through all data sets
lapply(dl, function(d) boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = d, outline = FALSE))
```

[image: Boxplot]

However, `boxplot(. outliers = TRUE)` does not really remove your outliers but extend your whiskers instead.

**ggplot**

For your second question, you can first hide your outliers via

```
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Status), outlier.shape = NA)
```

and then adjust the y-range via `ylim` depending on your data.

*Note*. Technically, you do not need to use `outlier.shape = NA` becasue if you use `ylim` points which are outside the range will be dropped anyways, but it makes the code a bit more verbose to show what you want to do.

**Example with a Builtin Dataset**

```
library(tidyverse)

## plot w/ outliers shown
ggplot(mt, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) + 
   geom_boxplot() + 
   facet_wrap(~am)

## plot with outliers removed
ggplot(mt, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) + 
   geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
   facet_wrap(~am) + 
   ylim(c(0, 50))
```

**Caveat**

In your update you added the plots and I saw that you have free scales, which will render this approach useless, because you cannot specify the `ylim` on a per panel 
basis.

Comment: I agree with you but 'ylim' will scale all the boxplots but as you can see on my images I need 'ylim' for each boxplots. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible to get the name? I split like you said, so I get a list of length: 7. Each data.frame of this list is a data frame for one variable (in the split). I want to put the associated variable name as the title of each boxplot.

Comment: The name is coded in the name of the list. You could use `purrr::iwalk` to loop through the list together with the respective name of the list item and use that in your boxplot. See `?purrr::iwalk`

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @thothal, I post the final code which works:

```
dl = split(samples_type, samples_type$variable)
par(mfrow = c(ceiling(sqrt(length(dl))),ceiling(sqrt(length(dl)))))
iwalk(dl, ~ boxplot(value ~ Status , data = .x,
      outline = FALSE,col=c("red", "limegreen"), main=.y))
```

"iwalk" from the package "purrr".

To remember, head of the the data frame **samples_type**:

```
Status   variable        value
PAT       SPP1        1,994629e+00
PAT       SPP1        1,179033e+00
PAT       SPP1        2,901539e+00
PAT       SPP1        1,140857e+00
PAT       SPP1        1,467056e+00
PAT       SPP1        2,579037e+00
```

The "Status" column can take two values: PAT or CON. The "variable" column can take many values: SPP1, CCL24, ENG56 ...